# sqlite3 on node.js 11.1.0 can't open database

Tags: node.js, sqlite, raspberry-pi, discord.js

I created a database with the newest version of SQLiteStudio. If the database is completely empty, then everything works fine, but already one single table will stop loading the database successfully.
This is the code I use for connecting to the database when the bot starts:

```
var path = "/home/pi/Desktop/MelloBot";

    const dbPath = require(path + '/ItemDatabase.db');

    let db = new sqlite3.Database(dbPath, sqlite3.OPEN_READWRITE, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err.message);

    }
        message.channel.send('Connected to the Item database.');
    });
```

And this is the SQLite command for my table:

```
CREATE TABLE Items (
Name STRING,
ID   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
);
```

And in the end, this is the error I get when connecting to a non-empty database:

```
/home/pi/Desktop/MelloBot/ItemDatabase.db:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { SQLite format 3
                                                                     ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.main (/home/pi/Desktop/MelloBot/adminCommands/item.js:9:24)
```

I haven't found any solution for this "Format"-error.

Comment: You can't just `require` your database. Require is for js files. The path to the db is without the require call. so it's `const dbPath = path + /ItemDatabase.db`

Comment: That solved it. Thanks very much! How could I not see that